# registering service which depends on MSSQLSERVER, Integrated security issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-services, windows-authentication

My auto-starting Windows Service written in C# depends on MS SQL Server and uses `Integrated Security=SSPI`

In the Installer I'm stating

```
this.serviceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] {"MSSQLSERVER"};
```

Unfortunately, during **auto-startup** my service **throws the exception**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "***" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

if I however **start it manually** later, it **works correctly** - connects to the database and works on it.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the real issue is not about user logon, it's about MS SQL Server not being **really** ready as soon as the service is ready. See [Connecting to SQL Server fails in autostart service, works when starting manually. SQL Server not ready, yet service is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594442/connecting-to-sql-server-fails-in-autostart-service-works-when-starting-manuall)